# Dependency of parameter to find maximum vanishes after simplification

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, probability-or-statistics, distributions

EDIT: It turns out I just made a dumb mistake:

`Simplify[Exp[x^2]*2^n*Pi*D[maxdist[n,x]/n*(1+Erf[x/Sqrt[2]])^(2-n),x]]`

A portion of my "factor" is actually inside the derivative. Thanks to everyone who helped!

I'm using *Mathematica* to try to solve: 
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1700486

The probability distribution function (PDF) of the maximum of n 
standard normally distributed variables is:

```
(2^(1/2 - n)*n*(1 + Erf[x/Sqrt[2]])^(-1 + n))/(E^(x^2/2)*Sqrt[Pi])
```

To find the mode, I take the derivative and set equal to 0. The 
"raw" derivative is:

```
(2^(1 - n)*(-1 + n)*n*(1 + Erf[x/Sqrt[2]])^(-2 + n))/(E^x^2*Pi) -  
 (2^(1/2 - n)*n*x*(1 + Erf[x/Sqrt[2]])^(-1 + n))/(E^(x^2/2)*Sqrt[Pi])
```

and `Simplify` will reduce it to:

```
-((n*(1 + Erf[x/Sqrt[2]])^(-2 + n)*(2 - 2*n + E^(x^2/2)*Sqrt[2*Pi]*x +  
    E^(x^2/2)*Sqrt[2*Pi]*x*Erf[x/Sqrt[2]]))/(2^n*E^x^2*Pi))
```

Since I only need to see when this value is $0$, I can multiply it by 
anything that's not $0$ (or undefined), in particular:

```
Exp[x^2] 2^n Pi/n (1 + Erf[x/Sqrt[2]])^(2 - n)
```

Multiplying the simplified derivative by that quantity yields:

```
2^n E^x^2 Pi (2^(1 - n)/(E^x^2 Pi) - (2^(1/2 - n) x (1 + Erf[x/Sqrt[2]])) /
 (E^(x^2/2) Sqrt[Pi]))
```

Simplifying again, we have:

```
2 - E^(x^2/2) Sqrt[2 Pi] x - E^(x^2/2) Sqrt[2 Pi] x Erf[x/Sqrt[2]]
```

The problem? **This value no longer depends on $n$**.

However, graphing the PDF for various values of $n$ shows that the mode changes:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if your calculations have gone astray somewhere. I seem to get a different result.

Below `pdf` is your expression for the PDF you are working with, `factor` is the non-zero expression by which you want to multiply your derivative:

```
pdf = (2^(1/2 - n)*n*(1 + Erf[x/Sqrt[2]])^(-1 + n))/(E^(x^2/2)*Sqrt[Pi]);
factor = Exp[x^2]*2^n*Pi/n*(1 + Erf[x/Sqrt[2]])^(2 - n);
```

Calculating `D[pdf, x] // Simplify` agrees with your raw and simplified results in the question. However, multiplying by your factor and simplifying did not remove the dependence on `n`:

```
D[pdf, x] factor // Simplify
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Solve[D[pdf, x] factor == 0, n]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I was about to write an answer, but I'll leave this comment instead: have a look at `FullSimplify[D[PDF[OrderDistribution[{NormalDistribution[], n}, n], x], x]]`.

Comment: Thanks, @MarcoB! As a minor note, finding the value of n for where the derivative is 0 is quite interesting, but I think I need the solution for x to find the mode :)

Comment: Something like `With[{n = 25}, x /. FindRoot[-2 + 2 n + Exp[x^2/2] Sqrt[2 π] x (-2 + Erfc[x/Sqrt[2]]), {x, -Sqrt[2] InverseErfc[2^(1 - 1/n)]}]]` then, @barry?

Comment: Yes, that's what I had been doing, and was hoping to find a closed form solution, but no luck, alas. https://github.com/barrycarter/bcapps/blob/master/STACK/bc-prob-max.m for the morbidly curious :)